# Unable to insert empty integer value in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO emp (EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO) 
VALUES (7369, 'SMITH', 'CLERK', 7902, 17-Dec-80, 800, '', 20)
```

Why it is not inserting as zero when passed as blank? The COMM column is 0 and not empty.

I want the column(COMM) as empty. I have also set the columns as NULL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370906/invalid-column-name-dec-in-sql?noredirect=1#comment104935173_59370906

Comment: @jarlh that question and this is totally different one

Comment: But you didn't learn much about providing the required information? Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: It is not you want the column empty, it is SQL server table definition dictates how row values should be, please give us more information

Comment: `... 800, null, 20 ...`

Comment: You cannot store an empty string `''` in an int column. And for some silly reason, SQL Server treats `''` as 0 in numeric context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put `''` as the value to insert into that **column**. You should be inserting `NULL`.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO emp(EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO) 
VALUES(7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,17-Dec-80,800,NULL,20)
```